# Cast OWL-S condition to SWRL

Tags: casting, conditional-statements, swrl

I want to cast some OWL-S conditions to SWRL, the cast is done but the result manipulation returns nullpointerexception. Here the code :

```
final OWLIndividualList<Condition> cs = service.getProfile().getConditions();
final ArrayList<ArrayList<URI>> conditions = new ArrayList<ArrayList<URI>>();
for (final Condition<?> c : cs){
   if (c.canCastTo(Condition.SWRL.class)){ // is it a SWRL condition?
      final Condition.SWRL sc = c.castTo(Condition.SWRL.class);
      for (final Atom a : sc.getBody()){...........
```

the last line returns :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Can anyone help me to deal with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is not linked to the java code but to the OWLS-S file syntaxe.
you can resolve this issue by replacing:

```
 <expr:expressionBody rdf:parseType="Literal">
```

which hold the SWRL precondition (or eventually the result), by:

```
<expr:expressionObject>
```